# Как работает данный метод сравнения строк?

Tags: c#

Подскажите, как работает сравнение внутри if? В msdn сказано, что StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase -  сравнение строк без учёт регистра, но тогда зачем здесь < 0?
symbol - какой-то символ, а вот words[i] - определенное слово, содержащееся на i-том месте в списке. И в каких случаях код внутри if вернет true, а в каких нет?

```
if (string.Compare(symbol, words[i], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0){}
```

Comment: `но тогда зачем здесь < 0?` — а разве на том же msdn  не сказано? https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/zkcaxw5y(v=vs.110).aspx  .... Возвращаемое значение .......................`в каких случаях код внутри if вернет true, а в каких нет?` — ну логично, что вернет `true`, когда `Compare` вернет значение меньше нуля

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, сказано, но что значит "положение в сортировке"?

Comment: `что значит "положение в сортировке"?` -  ну например есть слова "бомба, ад, ягодка"..... согласно логике сортировки их надо расположить в таком порядке 'ад, бомба, ягодка". А сейчас явно не так... вот они попарно сравниваются... в начале "бомба" и "ад". Слово "бомба" должно идти после "ад", поэтому результат `String.Compare("бомба", "ад", true)` - вернет 1, то есть расположить "бомба" дальше чем "ад" в сортировке.... при сравнении "ад" и "ягодка" получится что `String.Compare("ад", "ягодка", true)` - вернет -1, чтобы сортировщику дать понять, что "ад" находится  **до** "ягодка" и т.д..

Comment: @АлексейШиманский , вы указываете true в методе, а у меня стоит StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase, который вроде как логического оператора не возвращает. можете пояснить, для чего вам true?

Comment: `вроде как логического оператора не возвращает.` - так вы открывали msdn или нет?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский , я их не совсем понял. Там написано, что булево значение отвечает за IgnoreCase. Т.е. игнорировать регистр или нет, правильно понимаю?

Comment: Откройте примеры с перегрузкой метода с `StringComparison`, а не с IgnoreCase.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68589/discussion-between-iwprogrammer-and--).

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите. При сравнении у нас потенциально возможны три исхода: первый объект меньше второго, равен ему, или больше его. В функции `Compare` это традиционно кодируется возвращаемыми значениями меньше нуля, нулём или больше нуля.

Соответственно, `string.Compare(symbol, words[i], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) < 0` означает, что при сравнении у нас строка `symbol` оказалась меньше строки `words[i]` (то есть, при сортировке по возрастанию первая строка будет перед второй).

---

Сортировка `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` означает, что сравнение производится не учитывая разницу между большими и маленькими буквами (то есть, `"ABC"` и `"aBc"` считаются одинаковыми), и без учёта локали, по кодам символов (а значит, например, буква Ё не между Е и Ж).